# Reading Device tree node with Interrupt property

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, powerpc, device-tree

I have following snippets the from two different Device tree source.

```
UART1: serial@ef600400 {
              device_type = "serial";
              compatible = "ns16550";
              reg = <0xef600400 8>;
              virtual-reg = <0xef600400>;
              clock-frequency = <0x00a8c000>;
              current-speed = <0>;
              interrupt-parent = <&UIC0>;
              interrupts = <1 4>;
                    };


serial0: serial@4500 {
                    cell-index = <0>;
                    device_type = "serial";
                    compatible = "ns16550";
                    reg = <0x4500 0x100>;
                    clock-frequency = <0>;
                    interrupts = <42 2>;
                    interrupt-parent = <&mpic>;
            };
```

I would want to know What does interrupts = <1 4>; interrupts = <42 2>; stand for?

Where do we get <1 4> , <42 2> values from?

Comment: There is some information here but it looks like the values will be hardware specific: http://www.devicetree.org/Device_Tree_Usage

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar You will have to look at the device tree bindings for this device, but the first number usually indicates the interrupt line and the second usually indicates if it is rising edge triggered, falling edge, level triggered, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a little more context to determine what those `interrupts` properties represent. Taking something similar to your first example, let's look at `arch/powerpc/boot/dts/bamboo.dts`, which has the following:

```
        UART1: serial@ef600400 {
            device_type = "serial";
            compatible = "ns16550";
            reg = <0xef600400 0x00000008>;
            virtual-reg = <0xef600400>;
            clock-frequency = <0>;
            current-speed = <0>;
            interrupt-parent = <&UIC0>;
            interrupts = <0x1 0x4>;
        };
```

The `interrupts` property describes a connection from this device to the interrupt controller. Assuming that the controller has multiple inputs (ie, the interrupt lines), we need to find out which one of the lines that this device will interact with.

Different controllers may have different methods of demultiplexing their IRQs, hence the variation in property types. In this case, let's take a look at the interrupt controller. We see that the `serial@ef600400` node has the following property:

```
            interrupt-parent = <&UIC0>;
```

The `&UIC0` syntax tells us that there's a UIC0 label elsewhere in the device tree. That's our interrupt controller. If we find that label, we see:

```
UIC0: interrupt-controller0 {
    compatible = "ibm,uic-440ep","ibm,uic";
    interrupt-controller;
    cell-index = <0>;
    dcr-reg = <0x0c0 0x009>;
    #address-cells = <0>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    #interrupt-cells = <2>;
};
```

Firstly, we see that `#interrupt-cells` is 2 - this means that each interrupt descriptor occupies two cells. Since the serial device's `interrupt` property has two cells (0x1 and 0x4), this tells us that there's one interrupt line being described.

The `compatible` property tells us that this is an IBM UIC interrupt controller. If we take a look at the driver for this controller, we see:

```c
static struct irq_domain_ops uic_host_ops = {
    .map    = uic_host_map,
    .xlate  = irq_domain_xlate_twocell,
};
```

That xlate function is what's used to map the interrupt sources' `interrupts` properties to a hardware IRQ number (and possibly its IRQ type). The `irq_domain_xlate_twocell` function is pretty straightforward:

```c
int irq_domain_xlate_twocell(struct irq_domain *d, struct device_node *ctrlr,
            const u32 *intspec, unsigned int intsize,
            irq_hw_number_t *out_hwirq, unsigned int *out_type)
{
    if (WARN_ON(intsize < 2))
        return -EINVAL;
    *out_hwirq = intspec[0];
    *out_type = intspec[1] & IRQ_TYPE_SENSE_MASK;
    return 0;
}
```

So (and as Peter L mentioned in his comment), in this case the two cells `<0x1 0x4>` represent the interrupt line 1, and a level-high (0x4 == `IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH`) interrupt type.

Your second example is a little more complex: it uses an mpic interrupt controller, which has its own `xlate` function. Have a look at `mpic_host_xlate` in `arch/powerpc/sysdev/mpic.c` for the internal details.

Comment: so how can i find "IBM UIC interrupt controller" device driver?

dtc file says it is compatible to ibm-uic-440ep and ibm-uic but i can't find one of these drivers when i search them with these keywords.

is there a mapping between "driver name" and compatible parameter in the dts files?

Comment: The drivers are almost always matched to their devices using the "compatible" property in the device tree. If you grep for `ibm,uic` in the tree, you'll find the driver in `arch/powerpc/platforms/4xx/uic.c`. However, the UIC driver is a little different in that it does not use a match table. If you want further details, post a question and I can add a more elaborate answer.